# A question regarding Corollary 4.12 in Mumford's "Analytic construction of deg. Ab. Var."

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties, group-schemes

Let $S=Spec A$ be the spectrum of an integrally closed, excellent and Noetherian ring. In his paper, David Mumford constructs an $S$-group scheme $G$. He shows that the torsion of $G_s$ is $p$-divisible for every prime $p$ and every $s\in S$ and concludes that $G_s$ is thus connected and without unipotent radical. I do not know how he comes to that conclusion. Is there something I don't know?

Comment: Multiplication by $p$ on an additive group / vector group in characteristic $p$ is a zero map.  So the additive group is not $p$-divisible in characteristic $p$.

Comment: @JasonStarr So what? Excuse me if I am stupid.

Comment: I mean he shows that $G_s$ is of char $0$. What do I gain from this?

Comment: I do not have access to Mumford's paper.  What I can say is that $p$-divisibility rules out certain kinds of bad reduction.  Without looking at Mumford's paper at all, one possibility is that Mumford uses the technique (also used elsewhere to prove theorems about Abelian varieties) of showing that the family of Abelian varieties is the base change of a family with similar properties defined over a finite type scheme over $\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{Z}$.  If this family also satisfies $p$-divisibility then you are set: just reduce modulo maximal ideals having finite residue fields.

Comment: That doesn't help at all.

Comment: I just quickly read Mumford's article.  Nowhere in the article does he claim to deduce smoothness of the model from $p$-divisibility.  In the introduction he compares his construction to Tate's construction using $p$-adic uniformization.  But Mumford does not use that in his construction.

Comment: I am not talking about smoothness! I am talking about connectedness and no unipotent radical.

Comment: I see nowhere in Mumford’s article where he uses $p$-divisibility.  On what page do you see any claim that uses $p$-divisibility?

Comment: @JasonStarr On top of p. 24, Corollary (4.12). Clearly $p$-divisibility for all $p$ implies connectedness, but for the unipotent radical something seems to be missing. Perhaps the fact that the reduction mod $I$ is a torus is enough, but for non-affine groups I have trouble finding a reference.

Comment: Now I see the statement.  I am going to repeat my earlier suggestion.  Mumford does not require that $S$ is a DVR.  We can write our group scheme as the base change of a group scheme over a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, and then complete at an appropriate prime whose residue field has positive characteristic.  Then the $p$-divisibility does imply semi-Abelian reduction.  Since the semi-Abelian locus in the base scheme is open, that gives a way to prove semi-Abelian reduction over the original scheme.

Comment: @JasonStarr: If we know in general that the semi-abelian locus is open, then we can invoke this directly since the reduction mod $I$ is a torus. Even the computation of torsion is not needed.

Comment: Okay, now I understand the issue.  I still suggest reduction mod $p$.  For every characteristic $0$ fraction field $K$ of a finite type $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra $A$ that is an integral domain, for every finite type group $K$-scheme $G_K$, and for every nonconstant morphism of group $K$-schemes from $\mathbb{A}^1_K$ to $G_K$, after inverting a nonzero element of the integral domain, all of this extends over $\text{Spec}\ A$.  If we know that the reduction modulo all but finitely many primes $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ has $p$-divisible group of $p$-torsion points, this gives a contradiction.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly why is it so clear that $p$-divisibility of the torsion implies connectedness? Excuse me if I am stupid.

Comment: @TheThinWhistler: For a commutative algebraic group $G$ over an algebraically closed field $k$, and any prime $p$, I claim that if the $p$-torsion of $G$ is $p$-divisible then $G/G^0$ has order prime to $p$. This is easy if $[p]:G\to G$ is finite (in particular, if $p\neq\mathrm{char}(k)$): if $X$ is a connected component of maximal $p$-power order $p^m$, then $p^mX=G^0$, so $X$ contains an element of order $p^m$ which is not divisible by $p$ if $m>0$.

Comment: If $[p]:G\to G$ is not finite, I suggest you look at the image $H$ of $[p^n]$ for large $n$. It is ultimately independent of $n$, connected, $[p]:H\to H$ is surjective, and if $X$ is as before, then $p^nX=H$. (Here I assume that $G/G^0$ is a $p$-group; we can always reduce to that case). If someone has a reference or a simpler argument, I'll buy it.